# how to write a js that executes a method of an object belonging to a class of web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to develop an extension for chrome. I'm quite new with javaScropts working. To understand what i'm trying to do:
on this [page](http://speedvideo.net/embed-b1xme6w4683g.html) there is a video, i can use the console to start and stop the video with this:

```
var p = jwplayer.apply();
p.play();
p.pause();
```

How can i write this command in a javascript extention?

**EDIT**:
I've read your suggestion. But I'm really new with javascript, so it's difficult for me transpose those codes to my case. I want to point that i'm developing an extension, so i have to write a js that implement the code above **as** if i'm directly writing it into the console. Something like this (that of course it doesn't work):

```
$(window).ready(function() { 
    var p = jwplayer.apply();
    p.play();
});
```

I'm sorry for the stupid question, but it's my first experiment with javaScript.

Comment: There are a lot of free guides online about how to make chrome extensions. I've done it before and it's really easy. A quick google will do you good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Comment: Use method 2b from the linked answer and put only `var p = jwplayer.apply(); p.play();` inside function()